# Unable to get all children (dynamic loading) selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

This question has already been answered and one of the easiest ways is to get the tag name, if already known, within the element

```
    child_elements = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("<tag name>")
```

However, for the following element pasted, only **9 out of 25** instances of the tag name is returned. I am novice in JavaScript and thus, I am not able to zero down on the reason. In this example, I am trying to get the `dt` tag within the `ol` element. The code snippet I am using for that is,

```
    par_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('search-results__result-list')
    child_elements = par_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("dt")
```

The element skeleton/structure from the page source is shown in the image below:
(the structure is the same for all the `div` tags, as one is expanded to show for example.

[image]

I have also tried getting the class name **result-lockup__name** directly, and it still returns only **9** out of the **25** instances. What could be the reason?

**EDIT**

Initially,all the elements were not loaded, and thus I had to scroll through the page by

```
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
```

When the problem occurred once again, and I was not able to figure out, I raised this question. Apparently, it looks like even the scroll is not helping, as certain elements look **hidden**

[image]

After manually scrolling through them again, keeping the code in pause, I was able to "**enable**" them.

[image]

Is this a type of mask to save sites from being **scraped**? I feel now that I would probably have to scroll up in increments to reveal them all, but is there a smarter way?

Comment: Possibly element is loading and you need to scroll the page to get all the child elements.

Comment: Are you sure that all 25 instances there and not loaded dynamically? Can you share URL

Comment: @KunduK did that. The image I have posted is after the scroll, and a 5 sec delay. I just noticed that even after scroll with selenium, certain elements remain --pending. Upon scrolling manually and executing the code, I was able to get 25 instances

Comment: @Sers the url requires a login and hence I had to go with the screenshot. Otherwise, I could have shared the url. Please check the updated screenshot

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan : For some web app if you go to bottom of the page you won't find all the elements.if you go to scroll half of the page you might found all the elements.what you could do slowly scroll the page and keep adding element in the list that might help

Comment: @KunduK exactly the hypothesis I arrived at. Thank you for the suggest. How exactly do we do that in code? To **scroll up or down** slowly? somehow match with the page height and reach there in increments?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are loading dynamically and you need to scroll the page slowly to get all the child elements.Try the below code hopefully it will work.This is just an workaround.

```
element_list=[]
while True:
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    time.sleep(2)
    listlen_before=len(element_list)
    par_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('search-results__result-list')
    child_elements = par_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("dt")
    for ele in child_elements:
        if ele.text in element_list:
            continue
        else:
            element_list.append(ele.text)

    listlen_after = len(element_list)

    if listlen_before==listlen_after:
        break
```

Comment: edited it to return just the element for **Keys.DOWN**

Comment: I used window.scrollBy(0,x) and increment x, until it reaches the height of the web page. The **DOWN** is not scrolling much for this web app.

Comment: Some web apps DOWN is very helpful. However window.scrollBy(0,x) also good idea to increment x value.